# HTML form text input into an array

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, forms

I'm trying to convert data from one text input (form) into an array so I can run a loop on that array.

The user input should be a list of words (ex: phone email message) separated by space.
I want to insert that data into an array ([0] phone [1] email [2] message) and kinda stuck doing that.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is in a variable called `$input`, you can create an array of the words (separated by space) by using `explode()`:

```
$array = explode(' ', $input);
```